# form:submit unable to prevent default with return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, parsley.js

I want to validate a form with parsley.js, then submit via `jQuery.post`, which requires preventing the default form submission, but it's not working as expected.

The [docs](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#events-overview) for `form:submit` say:

> Triggered when after a form validation succeeds and before the form is actually submitted. Return `false` to interrupt submission.

However, I can't get that to work... the following code updates the `#alert` element, but then submits the form via the default browser level request. The `$.post` call doesn't seem to be performed.. it's never received by the server anyway.

```
$('.contact-form form').parsley().on('form:submit', function() {
  $('#alert')
    .text('Sending...')
  $.post({
    url: '/contact',
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function() {
      $('#alert')
        .text('Message successfully sent.')
    },
    error: function() {
      $('#alert')
        .removeClass('alert-success')
        .addClass('alert-danger')
        .text([
          'Sorry, a server error has occurred. ',
          'Your message was not sent.'
        ].join())
    }
  })
  return false
})
```

The following works as expected, validation is performed but the form is not submitted

```
$('.contact-form form').parsley().on('form:submit', function() {
  return false
}
```

I've tried things like this to no avail:

```
$('.contact-form form').parsley().on('form:submit', function(formInstance) {
  formInstance.submitEvent.preventDefault()
}
```

So I'm stumped...

This issue is different to [Preventing form submission after validation by parsley.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958507) which relates to binding jQuery's `submit` method to an `input` element instead of `form`.

Comment: Have you tried `formInstance.preventDefault()`?

Comment: yes I've tried `formInstance.preventDefault()`

Also the possible duplicate you linked relates to jQuery's `.submit` event being bound to an `input` element rather than the `form`. So mine is not the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has to be an error in the code before the `return false` that interrupts the function and thus never gets to return properly?

Comment: That's it! `form.submit` is not a function... Thanks, you're a god amongst men.